# Bootstrap Multiple grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I working on bootstrap grid. I want to make design like pic1.jpg. But I am not getting my expected design. pic2.jpg is the current scenario. I have given my code below.

pic1.jpg :-
!http://s16.postimg.org/xjrulxcmd/pic1.png

pic2.jpg :-
!http://s30.postimg.org/tu3h09ubl/pic2.png

So, Category3 must be the summation of category2, category4 and category5.
Also, I am trying to draw a circle at left side of Category1 but it is not working. Circle is coming after Category1. It should be responsive too, that is must.

My code :-

```html
<!-- Boostrap Help -->

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Example </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    p {
      padding: 50px;
      font-size: 32px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    
    #circle {
      background: #f00;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Category 1</p>
        <div id="circle"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>Category 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Category 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>Category 4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>Category 5</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The area that you're selecting as your div in the picture is actually just the `<p>Category 1</p>`. You've put `50px` padding all the way around it. Use firebug or something and you can inspect the elements and see what's causing the problem.

http://postimg.org/image/mveyj5v87/

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do with your provide above

**CSS**

```
 p{
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        height:100%;
}
#circle {
    background: #f00;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:30%;
}
.abc {
        position:relative;
}
.row-eq-height { /*-- This class is the trick make two column equal height --*/
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 abc">
            <p>Category 1</p>
            <div id="circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- This is how i make two column of your like you want, like wrap your Category 2,4,5 in one col and another col only for Category 3 and include the trick class - row-eq-height -->
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left:0">
            <div class="col-md-12"><p>Category 2</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><p>Category 4</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-12"><p style="margin-bottom:0">Category 5</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><p>Category 3</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me with that grid design? Like, height of category3 must be the summation of heights category2, category4, category5.

Comment: @Abhijit i think i already done that, you see the height of Cat 3 always the same height with the left col - combine of 3 Cat (2,,4,5)

Comment: Hi, but this is not working. It is same as it was before. Only that circle is ready. Please check it once.

Comment: @Abhijit if still what you post here it will work (i have check, nothing wrong with this); if you have change something, provide me the new code - you can come [here](http://www.codeply.com/go) make a demo, cant do anything without demo